# curl example of file download doesn't work

Tags: box-api

If I follow the box api 2.0 curl example to get the metadata of a file, I get the information. When I append /data to the url to download the file, curl says:

curl: (52) Empty reply from server

I did this with two files, both text files, same result.

The system here is OpenBSD 5.0.

In python 3, the same request raises an exception that says that the reply from the server contained a status line that is empty.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. The problem is that you need the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option set to true. Box will execute a redirection from the API call to the actual file. Without it, it will return an empty response.

Comment: for anyone curious how to do this on the command line it is the `-L` option, so, `curl -L <URL>`

Answer (score 1):

An empty response should be returned in the event that the file itself is empty. If, for instance, the two text files don't have any text in them, no text will be returned i.e. this appears to be expected behavior.

Comment: Well, ok, but both files do have text in them.

Comment: Hm, this seems to be happening for me as well–it might be a bug. Let me look into it, and I'll follow up here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same issue.  I have uploaded a file successfully, retrieved the file ID, then when I try to download the file, nothing happens.  Like the original poster mentioned, if I take off the "/data" portion of the URL, then I can get all of the info back about the file successfully.

Here is my "download code" that gets called from a form with a simple "Download File" button for that particular file ID.

```
$boxkey = "ThisIsMyAPIKey";
$auth_token = $_POST['auth_token'];
$url = "https://www.box.com/api/2.0/files/".$_POST['file_id']."/data";
$header = array("Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=".$boxkey."&auth_token=".$auth_token);

$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$url = "https://api.box.com/2.0/files/$fileId/content?access_token=$accessToken";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```